# Introducing: Number Slope™

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

**Number Slope™**<sup>1</sup> is an original<sup>2</sup> grid deduction puzzle similar to Sudoku. It is solved on an *n*-by-*n* grid, tiled with *n* *n*-ominoes. The rules are:

- Each number from 1 to *n* must occur once and only once in each row, column, and *n*-omino.
- Any row or column of adjacent cells *within each* n-*omino* must have numbers which are either increasing or decreasing along the row or column (these are called *slopes*).

That second rule may be a bit confusing, so here is a diagram showing the slopes in an 11-omino and a valid filling:

[image: slopes]

Here's another diagram, this time giving an example of the solving process for a 3x3 puzzle. The process is quite similar to solving a Sudoku, but note that in step 3 we can deduce how to fill the vertical tromino, since the numbers have to form a slope.

[image: solution]

Got that? Good. Now go solve this puzzle. Good luck!

[image: start]

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, to give it a more credible (read: Japanese) name, *Sukobai*, as [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com.au/?bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.142059868,d.dGo&biw=1094&bih=523&dpr=1.25&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/ja/number%20slope) tells me.
<sup>2</sup>At least, I *believe* it is. Tell me in the comments if it isn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these exist somewhere, but I don't remember what they're called.

Comment: I've seen "irregular" / jigsaw Sudokus before (it's easy to find them online too).  But the "slope" concept is new to me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What a fun puzzle!

Green means a note.
Blue means an important deduction.
Red means can be deduced by shallow sudoku logic, or shallow slope logic (I.e. If you have a 1 and 3, a 2 goes in between.)

Start off by focusing on 1s and 8s, because they're limited in where they can go (they have to be in a corner). In particular, that top middle area let's us deduce a 1.

[image]

Consider where 1 can be in row 3.

[image]

Consider where 2 can be in column 5.

[image]

Consider where 8 can be in column 5.

[image]

In the middle bottom area, 8 can only fit in row 7. Therefore, in the bottom right area, 8 cannot be in row 7. We get 8 has to be in column 7.

[image]

Since 8s are in corners, we can deduce those 8s, and chase 8s all around the board. This also lets us sort out that 1/8 thing at the top, and then chase 1s around the board.

[image]

[image]

Now that we've placed all 1s, 2s behave very similarly with needing to be in corners, or right next to ones. We can deduce the two blue twos, then chase.

[image]

Again, now that all 8s are placed, 7s behave similarly. We deduce the blue 7 in the bottom right, the red 7 at the top, then the blue 7 at the top, then chase.

[image]

Now most of our 7s are in, 6s behave similarly. Importantly, looking at the top middle area, we can use the only possible positions of 6 to deduce a 6 at the top right, then chase.

[image]

[image]

Now deduce the blue 4 (it can't be 3 or 5, and it has to be between 2 and 6), and it will give you the five right above it. That's enough to sudoku chase the rest of the puzzle easily.

[image]

Comment: You're too fast.  I was almost there :)

Comment: What can I say? I love a good grid-deduction puzzle :)

Comment: This is simply brilliant (and fast of course).

Comment: Nice solution! In the "twos" section you can have only the left one blue. The second blue comes straight from the two reds.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I simply took these screenshots as I solved the puzzle, and I noticed the top right blue first. It didn't lead to any sudoku chase, so I then found the bottom left one and I think I just left them both blue.